# Linear Algebra Eigenvalues question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

This question doesn't look too hard but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Let $A$ and $B$ be n x n matrices. Show that if none of the eigenvalues of A are equal to 1, then the matrix equation 
$XA + B = X$ will have a unique solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: if none of the eigenvalues of $A$ is equal to 1, then $I-A$ is invertible.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it helped me to figure it out!